# Graded combobox Menu Python Tkinter

Tags: jquery, python, tkinter, combobox, tkinter-canvas

How to make a graded combobox in python Tkinter?
Like if we choose a value from first combobox menu, then the next combobox menu will show only values that inside the first selected combobox value category.

This is my code:

```
BU = StringVar()
BU.set("")

def BU(BU_choices):
    s = BU.get()

BU_choices = ["DUM", "IND", "KAM", "RAP"]
BU_drop = OptionMenu(Canv, status, *BU_choices, command=BU)
BU_drop.config(bg="white", fg="dark blue", width=3, relief=GROOVE)
BU_drop.place(x=130, y=110)

sector = StringVar()
sector.set("")

def sector(sector_choices):
    s = sector.get()

sector_choices == selected_sector         
if BU.get() == "DUM":
    selected_sector = ["GRG", "LBO", "KBU", "PLS"]
elif BU.get() == "IND":
    selected_sector = ["BYS", "MER", "NGD", "PER"]
sector_drop = OptionMenu(Canv, status, *sector_choices, command=sector)
sector_drop.config(bg="white", fg="dark blue", width=3, relief=GROOVE)
sector_drop.place(x=130, y=150)
```

Any Suggest?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221673/tkinter-python-dependent-combobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code with some bugs fixed:

```
def on_BU_change(BU_selected):
    # remove current options in sector combobox
    menu = sector_drop['menu']
    menu.delete(0, 'end')
    # create new options for sector combobox based on selected value of BU combobox
    if BU_selected == 'DUM':
        selected_sectors = ['GRG', 'LBO', 'KBU', 'PLS']
    elif BU_selected == 'IND':
        selected_sectors = ['BYS', 'MER', 'NGD', 'PER']
    else:
        selected_sectors = ['']
    # clear the current selection of sector combobox
    sector.set('')
    # setup the sector combobox
    for item in selected_sectors:
        menu.add_command(label=item, command=lambda x=item: on_sector_change(x))

BU = StringVar()
BU_choices = ['DUM', 'IND', 'KAM', 'RAP']
BU_drop = OptionMenu(Canv, BU, *BU_choices, command=on_BU_change)
BU_drop.config(bg='white', fg='dark blue', width=3, relief=GROOVE)
BU_drop.place(x=130, y=110)

def on_sector_change(sector_selected):
    sector.set(sector_selected)

sector = StringVar()
sector_drop = OptionMenu(Canv, sector, '', command=on_sector_change)
sector_drop.config(bg='white', fg='dark blue', width=3, relief=GROOVE)
sector_drop.place(x=130, y=150)
```

Comment: Thank you acw1668 for your answer. You just solved my problem!!